# how do I check if a thread is still running?

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I want to check in viewDidLoad that a thread is running or not, 
how can I achieve such concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

`NSThread` has methods for determining **thread state**

```
isExecuting
isCancelled
isFinished
```

you can use these methods.

for example in viewDidLoad you can write

```
BOOL stillRunning = [[NSThread currentThread] isExecuting];
```

**UPDATION :**

`[NSThread currentThread]` will return current running thread. its static method of `NSThread` class.
for your own thread

```
BOOL isStillRunning = [yourThreadObject isExecuting];
```

Comment: but what is currentThread here, because I have my own thread, so how do I check that?

Comment: but when you will change the view, again again came back,then?

Comment: -(void)runThread{ } It is my Thread name, and I am writing like   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(runThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
 for calling this thread, so I am to go back, and come on same page, so viewDidLoad will apear again, so how can I check that still my runThread is running or not???????

Comment: is this the only other thread besides main thread? If you create thread using initWithTarget:selector then you can have its reference to check its state.

Comment: yes, it is only one thread beside main thread, now tell me how to check its status,

Comment: you will need reference of your thread to know about its status. Create a NSThread object using – initWithTarget:selector:object: method instead of detachedNewThread, you have to declare it globally then you can query its state.